# JPA Discriminator using Spring-Data Repositories and JPQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data

I have two entities in MySQL as below. The primary key of nnm_tran is a composite of id and source. The primary key of bargains is actually a foreign key link to the nnm_tran table
[image: Entities. Bargains inherits from nnm_tran]

I'm trying to use JPA inheritance to represent these.

**nnm_tran entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nnm_tran")
@IdClass(CommonTransactionKey.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "bargain_flag", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@DiscriminatorValue("N")
public class CommonTransaction {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String transactionId;

    @Column(name = "plan_number", nullable = false)
    private String planNumber;

    @Column(name = "tran_date")
    private LocalDateTime transactionDatetime;

    @Column(name = "bargain_flag")
    private String bargainFlag;
    ...
}
```

**bargains entity**

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "bargains")
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({ @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "nnm_tran_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "nnm_tran_source", referencedColumnName = "source") })
public class Bargain extends CommonTransaction implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "unit_price")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @Column(name = "client_price")
    private BigDecimal clientPrice;
    ...
}
```

I think so far this is all hooked up correctly. My problem comes when I attach a spring-data repository with a custom query.

**Repository**

```
public interface CommonTransactionRepository extends CrudRepository<CommonTransaction, CommonTransactionKey> {

    @Query("select t from CommonTransaction t left join IoPlan p ON t.planNumber = p.planNumber "
        + "where (p.planNumber is NULL or p.planNumber = '') "
        + "and t.transactionDatetime between ?1 and ?2 "
        + "and t.cancelled = false")
    public Iterable<CommonTransaction> findOrphanedTransactionsByTranDate(LocalDateTime fromDate, LocalDateTime toDate);
   ...
}
```

When this gets proxied and the method is executed it generates the SQL statement
`SELECT DISTINCT nnm_tran.bargain_flag FROM nnm_tran t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN io_plan t0 ON (t1.plan_number = t0.plan_number) WHERE ((((t0.plan_number IS NULL) OR (t0.plan_number = ?)) AND (t1.tran_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)) AND (t1.CANCELLED = ?))`

The issue with this is that the `nnm_tran` table is aliased to `t1` but the discriminator column is referencing the full table name `nnm_tran.bargain_flag`  The result is a lovely

```
UnitOfWork(17171249)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'nnm_tran.bargain_flag' in 'field list'
```

Question here is, am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in spring-data and/or eclipselink?

Versions: spring-data 1.7.2, Eclipselink 2.5.2, MySQL 5.6.28

Comment: I doubt that the posted JPA will result in the posted SQL query (the JPA query starts with `SELECT t FROM CommonTransaction t`, whereas the SQL query is `SELECT DISTINCT nnm_tran.bargain_flag FROM nnm_tran t1`. Are you posting actual code? I am also unable to reproduce the behaviour you have pointed to with the versions you have provided. You can run tests included in [my sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/36664835) to see the correct SQL being generated. You can copy the sample and tweak it to your code to see why you are getting incorrect SQL.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking the time and going to the effort of setting up a test for this. It has been useful in helping me see the wood amongst the trees. :-)  To answer your question, yes this is actual code and yes the SQL is the result of the JPA query.  I have managed to get to the bottom of this quirk and although not particularly elegant it works for me for now. I've detailed it in my answer.

Comment: EclipseLink may use a "select distinct discriminatorColumn" query to get the subclasses it will need to build and then issue separate queries for each class.  This is configurable as described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance#Example:_Configuring_JOINED_inheritance_to_use_an_outer_join  Try using a customizer to set it to use outer joins to read in subclasses in a single query, which it should use if there is ordering or pagination on the query.

Comment: @Chris Holy s**t snacks. That blows the pants off of my own solution. Added the customizer and was off and running. It did indeed just need to switch to outer joins. :-) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using @manish's sample app as a starting point I started layering back on the complexity that was missing and quickly stumbled across the thing causing the rogue SQL. It was down to the join I had performed in the JPQL

***NOTE:** If you've come here from the future then ignore the remainder of this answer and instead use @Chris's comment instead.*

Most of the time I don't need to look at or even think about the IoPlan table that can be seen in the `@Query`

```
@Query("select t from CommonTransaction t left join IoPlan p ON t.planNumber = p.planNumber "
    + "where (p.planNumber is NULL or p.planNumber = '') "
    + "and t.transactionDatetime between ?1 and ?2 "
    + "and t.cancelled = false")
```

and so this table is not a part of the `CommonTransaction` entity as a field. Even the result of this query doesn't really care because it's looking only as a one off for `CommonTransaction` with *no* associated join in the `IoPlan` table.

When I added the join back in to the sample app from @manish it all broke in the same way my app has in EclipseLink, but broke in a different way for Hibernate. Hibernate requires a field for you to join with, which if you ask me defeats the purpose of writing the join in the `@Query`. In fact in Hibernate you have to define the join purely in JPA so you might as well then use dot notation to access it in the JPQL.

Anyway, going along with this idea I tried adding a dummy field to hold an `IoPlan` in my `CommonTransaction` entity and it almost worked. It defaulted some of the join logic but it was closer

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.bargain_flag FROM nnm_tran t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN io_plan t0 ON ((t0.ID = t1.IOPLAN_ID) AND (t1.plan_number = t0.plan_number)) WHERE ((((t0.plan_number IS NULL) OR (t0.plan_number = ?)) AND (t1.tran_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)) AND (t1.CANCELLED = ?))
```

In this case `t1.IOPLAN_ID` and `t0.ID` don't exist. So I ended up defining the entire join in my `CommonTransaction` entity

```
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "plan_number", referencedColumnName = "plan_number")
    private IoPlan ioPlan;
```

and voila, it started working. It's not pretty and now I have a redundant join condition

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN io_plan t1 
ON ((t1.plan_number = t0.plan_number) AND (t0.plan_number = t1.plan_number))
```

but I can fix that. It's still annoying that I have to define a field for it whatsoever, I don't actually want or need it there, not to mention that the result from this query is returning `CommonTransaction` entities that have no `IoPlan` so the field will be permanently null.